# Webpack-dev-server not reload .html

Tags: javascript, web, webpack

Try to roll into the webpack. Using official docs. index.js reloads but index.html does not.
Command for build: webpack-dev-server --mode development --open

[explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0kFz.png) 
project in vs code

wp config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
  },
  devServer: {    
  }
};
```

package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
 },
```

Webpack ver:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
 }
```

*Do not ask HtmlWebpackPlugin, I think without this hack should work.

Comment: what is happening when you call `npm run dev`

Comment: https://ibb.co/dRdPQy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using HtmlWebpackPlugin, works well.

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html'
    })
]
```